# eventBus is listening duplicate events when component is loaded multiple times

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am facing very important and weird issue with vue.js eventBus.

My code is something like this,

```
mounted: function() {
    eventBus.$on('load-item', () => {
        // some loading data ajax 
    })
}
```

So, if I go first time in this component, it will execute only one time. But if I switch to other component and then again come back to this component, the event is emitting one time but the listener is executing this function 2 times. so every time I visit this component it is increasingly loading data. Third time 3 Ajax request. 4th time 4 ajax and so on.

I have tried following solution,

```
beforeDestroy: function () {
    eventBus.$off('load-item');
}
```

So above code will remove the listener, is it working only when it destroy the component. But in my case, if another view is using the same component then the same issue occurs.

My question is, what is the best way to remove event listener completely when we change page?

is there anything already there in vue.js?

I can explain in details if you are not clear about it.

Comment: so this component is used at more than 1 place at a time ? can you put the event listener in their common parent instead ?

Comment: I already tried, it works when there is a hierarchy. But what if 2 components are on same level. For example, I have reusable `filters` component and reusable `list-view` component. 
so if filters are updated, list view must update its data.

Comment: how can we do that in this scenario @JacobGoh ?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. It feels like an app architecture problem. Would you be able to extract the codes out to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: for a quick fix (that may not be a good practice), use [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#debounce) so that even if the event is triggered, the ajax won't be called too frequently

Comment: ok understand. @JacobGoh will try and update issue here

Comment: You can destroy the component with some simple `v-if` switch. By default its `true`, on your page change, change the value of `v-if` as `false`. It will get into beforeDestroy hook and will remove the listener

Comment: @Tugayİlik problem occurs when same components appear multiple time.

Comment: @rut2 I faced that problem too, my solution was simply passing a unique id to component as prop, then inside component checking it by its id before performing an action. 

Since your hook will be triggered for all components, on your emit event send current components id from parent as data . And make comparison according to that id

Answer (score 15):

Maybe you need `eventBus.$once` instead of `eventBus.$on`
When using $once after it's been executed it'll no longer called unless it was initialised again

Answer (score 1):

If unique event name. It can be applied as follows

```
mounted: function() {
    if (!eventBus._events['load-item']) {
        eventBus.$on('load-item', () => {
            // some loading data ajax 
        })
    }
}
```

However, I know that using vuex is better than using event bus.